# Installing gimp, webmin etc on backtrack 5

Tags: backtrack

I recently installed backtrack 5 on my desktop. Everything is pretty well. THe only problem is, i am not able to install apps like gimp, webmail etc which I think are dependent on ubuntu repos.

Is there any way to do it?
I also tried install synaptic, but that displayed dependencies error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Download gimp packages for ubuntu from it's site - http://www.gimp.org/. I think that backtrack 5 is based on ubuntu 10.04 lucid (not sure)
You get a deb package and install it with dpkg. The same is with the other packages.